# Install activejdbc for Java using Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, activejdbc

same as title, how to install activejdbc for java using Netbeans IDE? somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

- Create new Netbeans project
- Add dependent libraries:
- Right click on the newly created project -> Properties -> Libraries
- Add "Compile" libraries from Example of libraries: https://github.com/javalite/ant-example/tree/master/lib
- Add "Processor" libraries from Example of build time libraries: https://github.com/javalite/ant-example/tree/master/build_time_libs
- Close
- Click "Files" tab and open build.xml
- Add -post-compile target :

`<target name="-post-compile">
    <java classname="org.javalite.instrumentation.Main" failonerror="true">
        <sysproperty key="outputDirectory" value="${build.classes.dir}"></sysproperty>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${build.classes.dir}">
            <pathelement path="${javac.classpath}">
            <pathelement path="${javac.processorpath}">
        </pathelement></pathelement></pathelement></classpath>
    </java>
</target>`

- Save and close the file

If you are running project from Netbeans you need to perform additional step:

Right click on the project -> Properties -> Compiling and uncheck "Compile on save"